# Android Runtime.exec("arp") does not work

Tags: android, runtime.exec, arp

is there any way to start the command 'arp'.

My tries:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = rt
```

1. `.exec("arp")` -> got an `IOException`
2. `.exec("/proc/net/arp")` -> got an `IOException` as well (found out over the adb shell, that a `/proc/net/arp` exists)

Also tried a shell solution:

```
String sPrefix="/system/bin/sh -c 'proc/net/arp;";
String sPostfix="'";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

proc = rt.exec(sPrefix+sPostfix); // sh -c 'cd someplace; echo do something'
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = "";
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
   echo.append(line + "\n");
}
```

but got no return value.

Have anyone an idea :-/?

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/net/arp` is not a command, it's an ARP table. It's a text file you can read:

```
  StringBuffer echo = new StringBuffer();
  try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line = "";
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) echo.append(line + "\n");
    br.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, e.toString()); }
```

The table itself has the format:

```
IP address        HW type    Flags     HW address           Mask   Device
192.168.178.21    0x1        0x2       00:1a:2b:3c:4d:5e    *      tiwlan0
192.168.178.34    0x1        0x2       1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f    *      tiwlan1
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems newer versions of android (I think 4.0+) Don't keep this information anymore. The tables are blank.